# Change cell value depending on input of another cell with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

thanks to peoples help on here I have nearly finished what I set out to do yesterday/

I have included a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/uzW5e/

I would like it that when someone enters a value greater than 85 in the column headed Percentage Grade (class percGrade) the value 1 is put in the column headed Pass Level (class passLevel) but it isn't working?

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Module
        </th>
        <th>
            Percentage Grade
        </th>
        <th>
            Credits
        </th>
        <th>
            Pass Level
        </th>
        <th>
            WGC
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="multRow">
        <td>
            <input name="module" />
        </td>
         <td>
            <input name="percentageGrade" class="percGrade" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <input name="credits" class="credits"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="passLevel" class="passLevel"/>
        </td>
        <td>
                <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
        </td>
    </tr>



        <tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right">
    Total <span id="grandTotal">0</span>
</td>
```

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".multRow input").keyup(multInputs);

   function multInputs() {
       var mult = 0;
       // for each row:
       $("tr.multRow").each(function () {
           // check value entered for Percentage Grade 
           // & change Pass Level to value accordingly
           var $num = 0;
           if ($('.percGrade', this).val() > 85) {
               $num = 1;
               $('.passLevel',this).text($num);                
           }
           // get the values from this row:   
           var $val1 = $('.credits', this).val();
           var $val3 = $('.percGrade', this).val(); 
           var $val2 = $('.passLevel', this).val();
           var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
           $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
           mult += $total;
       });
       $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
   }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/uzW5e/1/. You have not added jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.passLevel` is a text field, you should use `.val` instead of `.text`:

```
$('.passLevel',this).val($num);
```